# wkhtmltopdf from list of files generates wrong TOC based on H tags

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit, python-pdfkit

I am using `python-pdfkit` as follows to generate a PDF:

```
pdfkit.from_file(list_of_files, toc=toc, cover=cover, cover_first=True, options=default_options)
```

My problem is regarding the table of contents that is generated:

> The table of contents is generated based on the H tags in the input
>   documents

If my html files are like:

index1.html

```
<h1>Title</h1>
...
[content]
```

index2.html

```
<h2>Subtitle</h2>
...
[content]
```

index3.html

```
<h3>Sub-subtitle</h3>
...
[content]
```

Since they are 3 **different** files, then the generated TOC is:

```
Title --------------------- Page x
Subtitle ------------------ Page y
Sub-subtitle -------------- Page z
```

Instead of

```
Title--------------------- Page x
   Subtitle -------------- Page y
      Sub-subtitle ------- Page z
```

I have tried merging all html files together but it is giving me a lot of problems with the internal links... linking to files instead to HTML `#IDs` gets tricky with a single HTML file all merged.

Any idea how to tell `wkhtmltopdf` to respect the `H tags` hierarchy without resetting it per file?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

After some discussion in the wkhtmltopdf github issues section, the only easy way of achieving this result is pre-parsing the HTML files to merge them all together.

See the following link for more details:https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/4310

Comment: This topic is being followed in `wkhtmltopdf`'s github repo https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/4310

Comment: please can you help me make the TOC? i believe i need to pass `toc = {'xsl-style-sheet': 'toc.xsl'}`, but i don't know what is supposed to go in that file...